# laravel belongsTo where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want data from table_entrypoint over table_a all rows from table_b with filtered table_c.

Tables:

```
table_entrypoint:
    id - int

table_a:
    id - int
    table_entrypoint_id - int
    table_b_id - int
    table_c_id - int|NULL

table_b:
    id - int

table_c:
    id - int
    table_b_int
```

table_entrypoint has many table_a. table_a has one table_b. table_b hast many table_c.

Something like `Entrypoint::first()->belongsTo('table_a')->with('table_b')->with('table_c')->get()` will create an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` for table_c. I want filterd by table_a.table_c_id an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. I prefered a function in table_a if there is no logic problems.

Here comes something from my code ...

My Model (hard cutted down) for table_a:

```
class Order extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'variant_id',
        'table_id',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function variant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Variant::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function table()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Table::class);
    }
}
```

My Model (hard cutted down) for table_b:

```
class Product extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    protected $with = [
        'variants',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function variants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Variant::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

My Model (hard cutted down) for table_c:

```
class Variant extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

If i call on tinker `App\Table::first()->orders()->with('product')->get()` i get the following result:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#712
     all: [
       App\Order {#711
         id: "1",
         product: App\Product {#725
           id: "1",
           name: "TEST",
           variants: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#735
             all: [
               App\Variant {#740
                 id: "1",
                 name: "Variant1",
               },
               App\Variant {#741
                 id: "2",
                 name: "Variant2",
               },
               [...]
             ],
           },
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

I want something like `App\Table::first()->orders()->with('productVariant')->get()` with a result of:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#712
     all: [
       App\Order {#711
         id: "1",
         product: App\Product {#725
           id: "1",
           name: "TEST",
           variant: App\Variant {#740
               id: "1",
               name: "Variant1",
             },
           },
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Is there a function in laravel `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` for this?

Comment: Did you try the [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) -
 `App\Table::first()->orders()->with('product.variant')->get()`?

Comment: Yes, i already try that. See `App\Table::first()->orders()->with('product')->get()` output. Variants is auto loaded.

Comment: Ahh sorry, so you would like to get just one (first) item from that relation? If so then use "Constraining Eager Loads" or define variant method with the hasOne relationship (you can freely lie to the engine that there is only one row :))

Comment: I have in `\App\Orders` the field `variant_id`. I want filter variants Collection by this id, and write the Model to `variant` in the `\App\Product` Model.